# Session variable in Codeigniter Not Working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hi i have created a session in Codeigniter i have set the session variable in my model. But after setting the session variable value when i call session variable in my view through Controller the session variable value becomes null. Any help???

**Update**

This is my Model where i set my session variable

```
function login ($username, $password)

    {
        $this->db->where('username' , $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if ($query->num_rows()>0)

        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $rows)
            {
                $data = array(

                    'user_name' => $rows->username,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                    'validated' => true
                );
            }

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                //$user = $rows->username;
                //$this->session->set_userdata('user_name', $user);

                return true;
        }

        else

        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Here is my controller from where i redirect to the view

```
public function verification()

    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');


        $result = $this->site_model->login($username, $password);


        //$result = $this->session->set_userdata('validated');

        if ($result)
        {
            //$this->admin();
            //$this->session->set_userdata('login_state', TRUE);

            redirect ('site/index');

        }
        else
        {

            redirect ('site/login');
            //$this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
```

i have called the `session_start();` in controller under `construct();`

and this is how i access the session variable in my view

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('user_name') != "") { ?>

.....
```

Comment: Could you paste your codes?

Comment: You have `session_start()` at the top of all the relevant files, I take it?

Comment: Are you using CI's session class? Or are you setting session variables manually? (If you don't know about the session class, go here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: i have updated my question with my code..

Comment: no need to call session_start() when using the Session Class, it does not utilize native PHP sessions, also if you expect only one result from your query you should use `$query->row()` it will return a single object, so you avoid the need for the foreach loop

Comment: i am calling session_start(); in my controller under construct() function but it didnt work. Should i call this function in my model as well???

Comment: Handling sessions in the Model layer of a CMV framework is not a good idea

Comment: "Sessions will typically run globally with each page load, so the Session class should either be initialized in your controller constructors, or it can be auto-loaded by the system. ".  [Check codeigniter's tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) and my full answer later in this post.

Comment: As always say, did you var_dump($this->session->userdata()); ?

Answer (score 1):

First of All in CI you don't need to use session_start() anywhere. only autoload session in config/autoload.php file.

Remove that session_start().
Try to use flashdata. Flashdata is temporary session mostly used in your type of case where We need to redirect user to another page and display some success or error message.

1. Set flashdata:
   $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
2. get flashdata:
   $this->session->flashdata('item');

Here is the documentation link http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

Answer (score 0):

use autoload applications/config/autoload.php, to add session liblary and remove session_start();

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Model pass post data vithout varibles, you can do like that:

controller:

```
public function verification()
{
     $result = $this->site_model->login();

      if ($result){
          redirect ('site/index');
      } else {
          redirect ('site/login');
      }
}
```

Model:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->db->where('username' , $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));

    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)

    {
        $res = $query->row_array();

        $data = array(
            'user_name' => $res['username'],
            'logged_in' => TRUE,
            'validated' => true
        );


        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

set the session variable in controller..this works for me nice

model

```
    function Login($email,$pass){
         $this->db->where('username' ,$email);
         $this->db->where('password',$pass);
         $query=$this->db->get('users');    
     if ($query->num_rows == 1) {           
    return true;     
     }      
     return FALSE;
    }
```

Controller :

```
        function varification(){
            $this->load->model('login_model');
    $email=$this->input->post('email');
    $pass=$this->input->post('pass');
    $success=$this->login_model->Login($email,$pass);
    if ($success) { 
                 $data = array(
                       'user_name' => $rows->username,
                       'logged_in' => TRUE,
                      'validated' => true
                 );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect ('site/index');
    } else{ // incorrect id or password
             redirect ('site/login');
            }
    }
```

now if you echo `<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name');?>` it will show the session username. you can echo it anywhere even in the view.hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the core php `session_start();`
Make Sure you Have loaded session library in autoload.php

as:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array("session");
```

or you can load session library manually : as

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

For Full Documentation You can refer : [Read Documentation](http://tutorialsplane.com/codeigniter-session-example/)

Answer (score 0):

please use this code to set session in codeigniter

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_session', $user_session_data);
```

I was having the same problem and it got resolved using this code.Hope it works for you too!.

Answer (score 0):

Setting session variables in Model, is not a good idea for any CMV framework (like codeigniter). Edit your Model's `login()` function so it returns a nice set of infos ...

```
function login ($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('username' , $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        if ($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $rows)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'user_name' => $rows->username,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                    'validated' => true
                );
            }
            return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

... and handle the session from the Controller.

```
public function verification()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $result = $this->site_model->login($username, $password);

        if ($result == false)
        {
            redirect ('site/login');
            //$this->load->view('login');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata($result);
            redirect ('site/index');
        }
    }
```

Also, in order to have session's data available to the view file, you need to pass them through your controller

```
$data['user_name'] = $this->session->userdata('user_name');
```

and then you can do whatever in your view file:

```
<?php if ($user_name != "") { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you need to change your model code
You are setting array in session and accessing direct user_name in session

I think below code will work for you,

```
function login ($username, $password)
{

    $this->db->where('username' , $username);

    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    $query = $this->db->get('users')->row();

    if (count($query) > 0)

    {

            $this->session->set_userdata('user_name', $query->username);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
            $this->session->set_userdata('validated', true);

            return true;
    }

    else

    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow below instructions.

make sure you have addedd session lib in autoload.php file so session will automatically loaded.

When you are using session in codigniter you don't have add session_start() at the start of the file because codigniter core system will handled this automatically.

It is good idea to set session variables in controller instead of model.

I hope this helps you in solving your problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, hope will help.. :D

in your model.. i copy paste code bellow but i change a little..

```
function login ($username, $password)

    {
        $this->db->where('username' , $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if ($query->result())//if any record
        {
            $rows = $query->row();

            $data = array(
                    'user_name' => $rows->username,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                    'validated' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;    
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

delete your session_start() in controller,, and then in your application/config/autoload.php

in this $autoload['libraries'] = array(); => add session like this
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

Thankyou.. :D

Answer (score 0):

user default php session, like *`session_start()`* and `$_SESSION`, it is working for me. in php codeignatore